# Jquery attribute selector using string concatenation in version 1.12.1

Tags: jquery

I want to use a variable as a selector attribute.

This is how I used to do this.

```
var variable = 'string';
$('[href=#'+variable+']'); #=> $('href=#string')
```

But in jquery version 1.12.1, this is no longer supported.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2824

So how would I refactor this without making it look too ugly?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The answer is right there in the link you posted in your question: "The following is a perfectly valid selector under 1.11.2:
`$('.class a[href=#anchor]');`

But fails under 1.12.0, and requires quotes:
`$('.class a[href="#anchor"]');`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add quotes around the internal link and it should work.

```
$('[href="#'+variable+'"]'); => $('href="#string"')
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.